# Is a potential data race a data race?

Tags: c++, multithreading, undefined-behavior, data-race

I am trying to understand where is the line between a data race and no date race and what are the consequences concerning undefined behavior.

Consider this example:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <functional>

void write(int delay, int& value, int target) {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(delay));
    value = target;
}

int main() {
    int x;
    std::srand(std::time(nullptr));
    auto t1 = std::thread(write, rand()%100, std::ref(x), 42);
    auto t2 = std::thread(write, rand()%100, std::ref(x), 24);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    std::cout << x;
}
```

Does this code have a data race always, or only sometimes? Is the behavior of the above code undefined according to the standard always, or only sometimes (depending on the outcome of `rand()`)?

PS: Of course I cannot know if the output will be `42` or `24`, but in the presence of undefined behavior I would not even expect either of the two with certainty,  it could be `123` or `"your cat ate my fish"`.

PPS: I do not care for high quality randomness, hence `rand()` is fine for this example.

Comment: From my understanding is a data race if two threads could potentially edit the same memory at the same time. This is the case in the provided example.

Comment: @HWilmer my understanding is similar, but I wasnt sure about the "potentially"

Comment: There is no guarantee that `sleep_for()` will sleep for *exactly* the amount of time specified and there is no guarantee as to what time it will take to spawn each thread.

Comment: Practically speaking, if you're using a 'typical' modern CPU (say intel x86_64), where integer assignment is always an atomic operation, the output is guaranteed to be either 42 or 24. (Surely your code is not portable if you do make such assumption)

Comment: @SPD i am more concerned about what the standard says because lots of my code is running on non-typical cpus (I had the language-lawyer tag first, but then removed it, because i realized that a lawyerish answer is not needed). If you like, replace `int` with `struct foo { int a,b,c,d; }`. Nevertheless, thanks for the input :)

Comment: Just a style comment: It seems strange to me that you would choose the name "value" for a parameter that refers to a variable, and "target" for a parameter that holds a value that you're going to store into the variable. I would have done just the opposite.

Comment: @SolomonSlow strange that you point it out, when writing I already knew that it isnt best naming ;). The idea was the `write` operates on a `value` and tries to set it to some `target` if that makes any sense

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This code *always* has a data race. There is no *happens-before* ordering between the two writes, so there is a data race.

The OS could in principle schedule the two threads so that both sleeps returned at the same time, as long as each sleep was at least as long as the specified delay time.

Comment: so sleeping has no influence on "happens before" ? I do need to use `mutex` or similar in any case, right?

Comment: well, sleeping was just for illustration. The real thing I am concerned about is when two threads write and only by the logic of the code I know that one happens before the other. The more I think about it the more I understand that without synchronisation I actually cannot know what happens first. Thanks for the answer

Comment: Yes, that is right: sleeping has no influence on "happens before", and you need to use a `mutex` or similar

Answer (score 2):

On architectures that can store a value to an `int` in a single bus cycle, you would either get `42` or `24` as the output, never `123` or any other value. However, theoretically you could have a multi-core processor where `int` is larger than the native data width, requiring multiple stores, in which case the stores of the two threads might interleave. This actually happens in practice on 32-bit processors when trying to store to a `uint64_t`.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, which 32-bit architectures still break down qword writes into multiple shorter ones? For unaligned access and across cache line borders, it's clear, but what about aligned writes within a single cache line?

Comment: @Hristo :  ARM CPU's. ARM is really a core design, not a processor, so it depends on the actual manufactorer. A really nice article can be found here . https://preshing.com/20130618/atomic-vs-non-atomic-operations/.

Comment: To add a historical datapoint: the Motorola 68000 had native 32-bit registers, but for cost and pin efficiency, it only had a 16-bit data bus, so while it only needed a single `move.l` instruction to store a 32-bit value to RAM, it took multiple bus cycles. There were multi-processor 68000 machines around.

Comment: @G.Sliepen: Even on a single-core processor, an optimizer could decide that the fastest way to change an object's value from 0x0123 to 0x0124 would be to replace just the bottom byte with 0x34, or perhaps increment the object, or maybe just increment the bottom byte.  I don't know to what extent optimizers look for those particular tweaks, but there are many real-world situations where they could improve efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

Many platforms can at essentially zero cost offer useful behavioral guarantees stronger than the Standard mandates, but unfortunately the Standard provides no means by which a program can determine what guarantees are available, and optimizers may rearrange code without regard for whether that would break programs that exploit guarantees the platform would otherwise provide at essentially zero cost.

For example, given `int x, y, *p;`, consider the following code snippet:

```
x = 0x0123;
y = *p;
... maybe some computations here that use up CPU registers
x = 0x0124;
```

An implementation might notice that between the stores of `0x0123` and `0x0124`, the value of `x` is read but not written, and it would thus be possible to change the latter write from a sequence like `mov ax,0124h / mov _x,ax` or `mov word [_x],0124h` (on the 8088, either sequence would be six bytes plus two memory operations) to `inc byte _x` (four bytes plus two memory operations).  Such code, however, might malfunction badly if there is an intervening write of some other value like 0x00FF.  Downstream code might regard any non-zero value of `x` as equally acceptable, and the source code has never requested that any value be written whose bottom byte is zero, but if the outside write stores 0x00FF just before the `inc byte _x` instruction, `x` could be left holding zero, quite unexpectedly.

In many cases, the cost of refraining from such optimizations would be less than the cost of including memory barriers sufficient to prevent data races, but unfortunately there is no nice means of specifying such semantics unless one replaces `x` with an "atomic int", which might require extra storage, and changes all accesses to `x` to explicitly use relaxed semantics.